# Capturing Database ID in Onlclick Method

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, onclick

I have a list view which is populated from a SQL database. I am using the following onlick code which detects when a cell is chosen :

```
ListView yourList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,  long arg3) {
                        Log.e("onClick",""+arg2);                                                                  
                        }   
    });
```

Currently this code is telling me what row has been clicked on. What I want to capture however is a field from the database called _ID. The order that the items appear in my list view is not the same order they are in the database, as I have sorted them alphbetically in my app code.

Can anyone help ?

EDIT I understand I can use arg3 - however it is returning 0 for every row. How do I correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is included in the callback.  If you look at the [documentation of the OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html), the method signature is:

```
 public abstract void onItemClick (
        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Notice 'id' field in your example is 'arg3'. This is the '_id' field from the database that you're looking for.

Comment: Addition: you have to provide the item ID to the list in your list `Adapter`. Otherwise, how'd it know.

Comment: Thanks - but arg3 is returning a value of 0 for every row ?

Comment: How do you populate the list in the first place?

Comment: From a custom adapter : public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
 ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
 ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Area")));
 ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AddressLine1")));

Comment: Ah worked it out - stupid mistake - _id in my database was actually a name field. Changed it to the unique ID field and all works properly. Thank you.